# "necessary to make" or "to make necessary" in this sentence from Nietzsche?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

A sentence from the second aphorism of the second essay of Nietzsche's "Zur Genealogie der Moral":

> Jene Aufgabe, ein Thier heranzuzüchten, das versprechen darf, schliesst, wie wir bereits begriffen haben, als Bedingung und Vorbereitung die nähere Aufgabe in sich, den Menschen zuerst bis zu einem gewissen Grade nothwendig, einförmig, gleich unter Gleichen, regelmässig und folglich berechenbar zu machen.

Walter Kaufmann's translation is:

> The task of breeding an animal with the right to make promises evidently embraces and presupposes as a preparatory task that one first makes men to a certain degree necessary, uniform, like among like, regular, and consequently calculable.

From context, it makes perfect sense to describe the task as "making men uniform, like among like, regular, and consequently calculable". Notice that all these attributes are closely related, even synonymous. It does *not* make much sense, from context, to say the task is to "make men necessary". "Necessary" is very different from "uniform", "calculable".

Is there an alternative way to understand this sentence, so that "nothwendig" is not parallel with "einförmig", "gleich unter Gleichen", etc.? Perhaps it is "...necessary to make man...", not "...to make man necessary..."? Or perhaps there is a subtle meaning of "nothwendig", rendering it roughly synonymous to "predictable"?

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, Kaufmann is absolutely right.
Nietzsche postulates "the preparatory *task of making men to a certain degree necessary* [...] calculable."

---

1. No reasonable interpretation of the **syntax** will afford you the translation "it is necessary to make men uniform etc."

> Jene *Aufgabe*, ein Thier *heranzuzüchten* [...] schliesst [...] die nähere *Aufgabe* in sich, den Menschen [...] *zu machen*.

What we have here is the logical, presuppositional pairing of two instances of "Aufgabe", a noun that typically takes (requires) an infinitive clause. The symmetry extends to the dependent clauses themselves and their semantics: "ein *Thier* heranzuzüchten" and "den *Menschen* [...] zu machen".

Note that "die Aufgabe" *requires* a dependent clause, just as the infinitive clause "zu machen" *requires* a governing (verb, adjective or) noun such as "Aufgabe".

> (1) Ich *befehle*, den Menschen... zu machen.

> (2) Es ist *notwendig*, den Menschen... zu machen.

> (3) Wir haben die *Aufgabe*, den Menschen... zu machen.

> (N) die Aufgabe, den Menschen zuerst bis zu einem gewissen Grade nothwendig, einförmig, [...] berechenbar zu machen.

Syntactically speaking, the natural reading of (N) is to connect "die Aufgabe" with "einförmig, [...] berechenbar zu machen" *directly*, as in (3). If you let "notwendig" step in to govern the "zu machen" clause, as in (2), you would take away the dependent clause that "the Aufgabe" requires and leave it dangling. This makes it a very unlikely reading of (N).

Instead, the noun *Aufgabe* governs the infinitive clause *zu machen* + an array of attributes that are all on a par: "making men necessary, ... predictable".

Syntactically speaking, Kaufmann is right.

---

2. **Semantically** (and philosophically) speaking, Nietzsche's connecting "nothwendig" with "regelmässig" and "berechenbar" makes good sense and has a long tradition behind it. All these attributes are closely related and somewhat synonymous, even "necessary".

First, while you seem to read "nothwendig" as implying an inflexible, exceptionless, *absolutely* deterministic necessity, note that in Nietzsche's passage, "nothwendig" is *qualified*: "bis zu einem gewissen Grade".
The individual is to some, even to a large extent, *determined*; that is,
not absolutely free, but rather (somewhat) controlled by its habits, influenced by its education, conforming to certain rules. All this makes it *likely* to behave a certain way, hence *predictable* ("berechenbar").

And this is Nietzsche's philosophical point here: raising *men* who conform to the expectations of morality is akin to creating *trained animals* that are influenced, somewhat controlled, by behavioural laws (in fact, he calls it "ein *Thier*, das versprechen darf").

This view of animals is in line with a broadly Cartesian, or [Kantian](https://philarchive.org/archive/NARKOD), tradition that views the "brutes" as *determined and bound by the laws of nature (and nurture)*; to some extent *necessitated* (*"nothwendig"*) to act by those laws, or *rules* (*"regelmässig"*), therefore *uniform* in their behavior (*"einförmig"*).

(The more extreme view would be Descartes' assumption that animals are just *machines* and their behavior is *strictly* necessary and deterministic; Nietzsche's contemporaries in philosophy and the life sciences would soften this assumption but still go with a view of behavior as *somewhat* deterministic: "*bis zu einem gewissen Grade* nothwendig".)

---

There is no need to doubt Kaufmann's translation, which (at least in this passage) is spot on.

Comment: Your analysis of Nietzsche's meaning is excellent but even a native German speaker will stumble over the use of 'nothwendig' in this sentence. I can't picture a modern German sentence using 'notwendig' in a similar construction.

Comment: @quarague Yes, good point. Nietzsche does his best to avoid the strictly technical style of many other philosophers, but he still presupposes a somewhat specialized vocabulary.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer! Yes, right before I submitted the question, it occurred to me that maybe "making a man necessary" means something like "making a man's behavior a necessary consequence of his circumstances [to a certain extent]", which is making him predictable. To my ear, this writing style sounded more like Sartre or a postmodernist than Nietzsche, though!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point to a dictionary that supports this interpretation of the word *notwendig*. As it stands, this answer seems incorrect to me. If a man is *notwendig*, then he *must necessarily exist* by the laws of nature/logic, or he is required for some purpose. But it is not a quality of his behaviour.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I don't have any good examples at hand, but I think many philosophers constantly use language in this very loose way. I am thinking especially of twentieth century French philosophers I've read in translation. It's almost a poetical style. It frustrates many readers, like me, who think it's intentionally obscure abuse of language and meaning. (I think Hegelians were attacked on similar grounds.) Nietzsche only rarely abuses language in this manner. I think he may have done so in this case.

Comment: 1/2 I might have overestimated the (relative) clarity of N.s use of this concept (relying on my own philosophical training and sensibility). Yes, it is an unusual meaning of the word "notwendig"; yes, it is not what one would find in a dictionary (though see the [Goethe quote](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73380/) provided by Paul Frost). But this is a fundamental MO of (Western) philosophy: writers often introduce *new* terminology or *expand* the use of existing terms... sometimes explicitly (via definition), sometimes even bc of their idiolect. ...

Comment: 2/2 ... @SebastianKoppehel: I find it normal (given my experiences reading Plato, Aristotle, Descartes, Spinoza, Leibniz, Kant, Nietzsche...) that a writer would *not always* stick to received *dictionary* meanings of words. An interpretation that can't be mapped 1-to-1 onto the dictionary can still be correct. And yes (@Will), Nietzsche does sometimes use a *looser*, associative style. However, I'd not lump him together with Hegel (mostly incomprehensible, 100% idiolect) or the French continentals (very loose). Nietzsche (apart from *Zarathustra*) is still relatively "well-behaved", as goes.

Answer (score 3):

The word "notwendig" occurs quite often in [Nietzsche's text](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/nietzsch/genealog/geneal01.html). In practically all instances it is used in the modern sense of "necessary", but the quotation given in the question exhibits an exceptional (not to say strange) use.

The comma is definitely intended. Let me give some quotations proving this.

> **Zweite Abhandlung: »Schuld«, »schlechtes Gewissen« und Verwandtes.**

> 1. 

> Ein Thier heranzüchten, das *versprechen* darf – ist das nicht gerade jene paradoxe Aufgabe selbst, welche sich die Natur in Hinsicht auf den Menschen gestellt hat? ist es nicht das eigentliche Problem vom Menschen?  [...]  wie muss dazu der Mensch selbst vorerst *berechenbar, regelmässig, nothwendig* geworden sein, auch sich selbst für seine eigne Vorstellung, um endlich dergestalt, wie es ein Versprechender thut, für sich als *Zukunft* gut sagen zu können!

> 2. 

> Jene Aufgabe, ein Thier heranzuzüchten, das versprechen darf, schliesst, wie wir bereits begriffen haben, als Bedingung und Vorbereitung die nähere Aufgabe in sich, den Menschen zuerst bis zu einem gewissen Grade nothwendig, einförmig, gleich unter Gleichen, regelmässig und folglich berechenbar zu *machen*.

The sentence "wie muss dazu der Mensch selbst vorerst berechenbar, regelmässig, nothwendig geworden sein" shows that Nietzsche uses "notwendig" as an attribute of man. Therefore we can agree that Nietzsche says (in condensed form)

> Jene Aufgabe, ein Thier heranzuzüchten, schliesst die Aufgabe in sich, den Menschen nothwendig zu machen.

As a digression let me mention that the relation between "Mensch" and "Thier" is intensively discussed in **Erste Abhandlung: »Gut und Böse«, »Gut und Schlecht«** culminating in

> 11. 
>
> Gesetzt, dass es wahr wäre, was jetzt jedenfalls als »Wahrheit« geglaubt wird, dass es eben der Sinn aller Cultur sei, aus dem Raubthiere »Mensch« ein zahmes und civilisirtes Thier, ein *Hausthier* herauszuzüchten, ...

To be honest, I am not sure what Nietzsche means by *den Menschen nothwendig machen*. Certainly he had his own world of ideas which may be strange to modern readers, but we should not brush it away as a Nietzschean oddity.

Here are two quotations form [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/) proving that Nietzsche is in a certain tradition.

> [Q1](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/nothwendig)
> es ist doch gewisz, dasz in der welt **den menschen nichts nothwendig macht**, als die liebe. Göthe 16, 72.

> [Q2](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/nothwendigkeit)
> die nothwendigkeit, deren strengem gesetze kein naturwesen sich entziehen kann. 10, 142; nach dem gesetz der nothwendigkeit. 10, 167; ein werk der nothwendigkeit. 10, 71; der mensch allein hat .. das vorrecht in den ring der nothwendigkeit .. durch seinen willen zu greifen. 10, 88; der mensch, der eigentlich auf seiner höchsten stelle da ist um der natur zu gebieten, um sich und die seinigen von der gewaltthätigen nothwendigkeit zu befreien. Göthe 22, 215; **ob sie (thiere) uns gleich so nahe stehen, so scheinen sie doch durch eine unendliche kluft von uns getrennt und in das reich der nothwendigkeit verwiesen**. 48, 13.

It seems to me that the second quotation points to the dichotomy *Freiheit / Notwendigkeit (freedom / obligation)* which is a classic philosophical concept. Understanding *Notwendigkeit* as the negation of *Freiheit*, the adjective *notwendig* would be the negation of *frei*. In other words, in Nietzsches's text "nothwendig" should be understood as "unfrei", "durch Pflichten gebunden" ("bound by human obligations").

Comment: Q1 from *Werther* is a great catch! An exactly comparable use case: *notwendig* as adjective.

Comment: Thank you for this very thoughtful answer. I think the consensus is as you suggest, Freiheit / Notwendigkeit. Although this is a rare usage for N (and others) of notwendig, this meaning fits the context perfectly. It's a rare departure from N's crystal clear writing style in Genealogy, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It could just be a spurious comma.  If the phrase were

> den Menschen zuerst bis zu einem gewissen Grade nothwendig einförmig, gleich unter Gleichen, etc. zu machen.

*nothwendig* would be an adverb modifying the predications (either just *einförmig*, or the whole list -- this is ambiguous).

> to make man necessarily uniform, equal amongst equals, etc.

which would indeed sound more likely (at least to me), and fits the tone of Nietzsche's writing.

I suggest you compare your text with some other editions of the same work, ideally a critical edition. (It might even be that the comma occurs in all editions, but is considered an original error.)

Comment: https://archive.org/details/zurgenealogieder00niet/page/42/mode/2up The same phrasing occurs two sentences prior: *wie muss dazu der Mensch selbst vorerst berechenbar, regelmässig, nothwendig geworden sein*.

Comment: Ah, that makes my hypothesis very unlikely.

Comment: DWB has a definition "die unmöglichkeit des gegentheils ausdrückend, dasz etwas seiner natur oder den verhältnissen nach so sein oder geschehen musz, nicht anders sein oder geschehen kann", which indeed sounds very Nietzschean.

Comment: Good try, thanks, although it probably misses...

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't see another possibility of translating the word 'nothwendig' (modern spelling 'notwendig') here. It can't mean "it's necessary to make man uniform,...", because the first part of the sentence allready states that it's about a prerequisite.

Clearly, I wouldn't use the word in this context nowadays. There could also have been a shift in meaning, but probably not for "predictable", but for "necessary" in the sense of "indispensable".

[This answer assumes the comma is intended]